# Filtering a Column for distinct set of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-schema

I have a table with Name, ID, and Car.

I want to return *distinct* Names and IDs of People that **ONLY** have either a Honda or Ford.

If they have either a Honda or Ford or both this is okay & return values. However if they have both **AND** another make (such as bob's case below) then don't return the name/ID.

Table:

```
Name ID   Car
BOB 21112 Honda  
Ame 32112 Honda 
BOB 21112 FORD
**BOB 21112 Dodge** --disqualifies bob from output
Ale 12322 Ford
Ame 32112 Ford
Sam 52412 Honda
```

Output:

```
Name ID   Car
Ame 21112 Honda, Ford   
Ale 32112 Ford 
Sam 52412 Honda
```

The output doesn't necessarily have to look like above, but just would like to identify the distinct names and IDs for people meeting this criteria.

I tried something like the following below, but I think this also counts cases if a name has other makes of cars.

```
Select t.Name, t.ID, t.Car
FROM table t
WHERE t.name = 'Honda' OR t.name = 'Ford'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return distinct Names and IDs of People that ONLY have either a Honda or Ford.

I would suggest using aggregation:

```
select name, id, array_agg(car)
from t
group by name, id
having count(*) filter (where car not in ('Honda', 'Ford')) = 0;
```

This puts the cars list in an array.  If you want separate rows (and perhaps other columns), you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where name not in ('Honda', 'Ford')) over (partition by name, id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 0;
```